# Extract Page from multiple pdf files

Tags: windows-7

I have 50 PDFs files and I want to extract first page of each file i do not know how it is to be done? kindly help me for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

many ways to skin a cat.  You are on windows?  First install cygwin from cygwin.org.

Install pdftk from here
https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

then open a cygwin shell

pdftk (pdf toolkit) is open source and can extract a given page.

if you write these 4 lines code into a file called get-page-one.sh
(you'll have to change the path to the pdftk.exe executable)

```
#/bin/bash
for i in *pdf; do
/path/to/pdftk.exe "$i" cat 1 output "new-$i"; 
done;
```

then run it with sh get-page-one.sh

it will create a new pdf prefixed with new- for every pdf in the directory you are in.  Stuff all your pdfs into the same dir first.

Pingers